# javascript function return failure

Tags: javascript, return

[image]

After checking the radio button clicked, I wanted to go back if the button wasn't checked. But the return keyword doesn't work and I can't understand because the other similar part works well. Please let me know what's wrong!!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. - do NOT post IMAGES of code, but actual code

Comment: Please don't post images, post your code as text here, so people can help you.

Comment: How do you use this function? What you mean `return does not work`?

Comment: are you close the if statment with `}` ? in your picture it dosn't closed